# Maths help on function to return number of items in container

Tags: math, algebra, differential-equations

This should be simple enough but the maths for this eludes me. I am looking to express this in C++ but some psuedo code will happily do, or just the maths really.

The function will be given a number of a container and it will return the number of items in that container. The number of items is based on their number and halves at certain number height.

The first halving is at number 43,200 and then every time after it is the gap number of containers between the previous halving plus 43,200

It may sounds confusing, it will look like the following.

```
1  to 43200 = 512
43201 to 86400 = 256
86401 to 129600 = 128
129601 to 172800 = 64
172801 to 216000 = 32
216001 to 259200 = 16
and so
```

So if a number up to 43,200 is given the result is 512, the number 130,000 will return 64. The value can be less than 1 taking up several decimal places.

Comment: So however many 43200s there are in the number is how many divisions by 2 are done on 512. Repeated division is an exponent/root, or a bit shift for dividing by 2, but you said it can go between 0 and 1, so that won't always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
global halvingInterval = 43200
global startingInventory = 512

def boxInventory(boxNumber):
    currentInventory = startingInventory
    while(boxNumber > halvingInterval):
        currentInventory = currentInventory/2
        boxNumber -= halvingInterval
    return currentInventory
```

This code will take the box number.  It will keep subtracting the halving interval until you get to the right inventory area, and then return the inventory when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
      N = (noitems + 1) / 43200;
      L2 = log(512) / log(2);
      answer = exp( log(2) * (1 + L2 - N) );
```